# Jackson: programmatically determine subtypes

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson

Given an arbitrary `Class` object, what is the best way to determine the subtypes of that class registered with Jackson?

For example, here's a simple case where classes `Lion` and `Penguin` are subtypes of `Animal`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Lion.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Penguin.class)})
public static abstract class Animal {}

@JsonTypeName("Lion")
public static class Lion extends Animal {}

@JsonTypeName("Penguin")
public static class Penguin extends Animal {}
```

My dream function would look like:

```
List<Class> getSubTypeClasses(Class c) {...}
```

where `getSubTypeClasses(Animal.class)` would return `Lion` and `Penguin`.

If the Jackson API doesn't provide a convenient way to get this information I will read the annotations manually, but it would be nice to know of a technique compatible with *any* `AnnotationIntrospector` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `ai.findSubTypes(ac)` you may use `mapper.getSubtypeResolver().collectAndResolveSubtypes(ac, config, ai)`.
I've not tested it with registered subtypes but looking at the code it should work.

Comment: Just confirmed this approach works with registered subtypes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no mechanism for doing that. But you could file a request for adding something like this: given a base class, return a set of known sub-types along with type ids used for them, and the default implementation use. This seems like a reasonable thing to provide access for.

In the meantime (new feature could be available for 2.3, so it'd take some time), have a look at `AnnotationIntrospector` and see what methdods are available there, and how `jackson-databind` uses it to build mapping information. You should not have to write all of that manually, even without accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to StaxMan for nudging me in the right direction. Here's a solution for Jaxen 2.2.3:

```
public static List<Class> getSubtypeClasses(ObjectMapper mapper, Class c) {
    return getSubtypeClasses(mapper.getDeserializationConfig(), c);
}

public static List<Class> getSubtypeClasses(MapperConfig config, Class c) {
    AnnotationIntrospector ai = config.getAnnotationIntrospector();
    AnnotatedClass ac = AnnotatedClass.constructWithoutSuperTypes(c, ai, config);
    List<NamedType> subtypes = ai.findSubtypes(ac);

    List<Class> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (subtypes != null) {
        for (NamedType subtype : subtypes) {
            result.add(subtype.getType());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just discovered this "solution" doesn't recognize classes registered via ObjectMapper.registerSubtypes()  :-(

Answer (score 0):

To access the SubTypes annotations of a super class you can use the JacksonAnnotationIntrospector:

```
    AnnotationIntrospector annotationInspector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();

    JavaType superClassType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().uncheckedSimpleType(Animal.class);

    AnnotatedClass annotatedClass = AnnotatedClass.construct(superClassType,new ObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig());

    List<NamedType> subtypes = annotationInspector.findSubtypes(annotatedClass);
```